Read lines of Txt file, edit specific lines, then write full Txt file to new file - C#
I'd like to read a Txt file with parameters and values then update the values of specific parameters. I don't know the original value of the parameter before changing but have a list of parameter values that need changed. Writing the entire file with changed values to a new file is my goal.
I'm currently able to find the parameters, replace the lines with updated string, and write to a new file.
Structure of text file:
Parameter1=1.5
Parameter2=2.0
Parameter3=0.5

Output of new file when replacing Parameter1 and Parameter3:
Parameter1=0.7
Parameter3=3.0

Ideal output:
Parameter1=0.7
Parameter2=2.0
Parameter3=3.0

private string ProcessParameterUpdates(string selectedDPVFile, string parameterName, string parameterNameAndValue)
{
    List<string> dpvLines = new List<string>();
    string dpvLine;
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(selectedDPVFile))
    {
        string fileSelectedDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(selectedDPVFile);
        string outputFileName = Path.Combine(fileSelectedDirectory, "UpdatedParameters.dpv");

        while ((dpvLine = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            if (dpvLine.Contains(parameterName))
            {
                dpvLines.Add(dpvLine);
                dpvLine = dpvLine.Replace(dpvLine, parameterNameAndValue);
                if (File.ReadLines(outputFileName).Contains(parameterNameAndValue))
                {
                    writeWindow.SelectionColor = Color.DarkOrange;
                    writeWindow.AppendText("Parameter already updated: " + parameterNameAndValue + "\n");
                    Debug.WriteLine("Parameter already updated: " + parameterNameAndValue + "\n");
                    dpvLine = reader.ReadLine();
                    writeWindow.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
                else
                {
                    File.AppendAllText(outputFileName, dpvLine + "\n");
                    writeWindow.AppendText(dpvLine + "\n");
                    Debug.WriteLine(dpvLine + "\n");
                }
            }
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
    return selectedDPVFile;
}


I suggest that you change the way the program works: read the data into something like a Dictionary<string, string>, make the changes (which may include additions) to the Dictionary, and then write the Dictionary keys and values to the new file.

Does this do the job for you?
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string inputFile = @"e:\test.txt";
    string outputFile = @"e:\test2.txt";

    Dictionary<string, string> updates = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        string[] parts = args[i].Split('=');
        string param = parts[0].Trim();
        string value = parts[1].Trim();
        updates[param] = value;
    }

    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(inputFile);
    List<string> updatedLines = new List<string>();

    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string[] parts = line.Split('=');
        string param = parts[0].Trim();
        string value = parts[1].Trim();

        if (updates.ContainsKey(param))
        {
            value = updates[param];
        }

        updatedLines.Add($"{param}={value}");
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(outputFile, updatedLines);
}

I assumed you will be passing params to the program as args.
It should be easy to change to any source.
You run the program as this:
ConsoleApp1.exe Parameter1=0.7 Parameter3=3.0

